# Переименовать папку ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛИ в USERS?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Знаю, что нужно удалить это в desktop.ini,

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
LocalizedResourceName=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-21813
```

но после удаления и сохранения, говорит что недостаточно прав и т.д.
Блокнот через администратора запускал - не помогло. Как быть?

Comment: Кто говорит? Недостаточно прав для чего?

Comment: Для сохранения файла, сообщение от Windows вылезает

Comment: значит блокнот открыт не через администратора